# Issue with estimateNetwork function in mgm package

Tags: r, networking

I am trying to run a mixed graphical model using the mgm package. This is my code thus far. I put asterisks around the last command, which is the one I can't seem to run. Can someone please advise?

```
library(haven)
    > flordiss <- read_sav("C:/Users/schul/OneDrive/Desktop/flordiss.sav")
    > View(flordiss)
    > library(mgm)
    This is mgm 1.2-13
    Please report issues on Github: https://github.com/jmbh/mgm/issues
    > library(huge)
    > library(glasso)
    > library(qgraph)
    > library(bootnet)
    Loading required package: ggplot2
    This is bootnet 1.5
    For questions and issues, please see github.com/SachaEpskamp/bootnet.
    > mydata<-flordiss
    > mydata_matrix <- as.matrix(mydata)
    > my_model <- estimateNetwork(mydata_matrix, reg = "mgl", standardize = TRUE)
    Error in do.call(.input$estimator, c(list(data), .input$arguments)) : 
    'what' must be a function or character string
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In formals(fun) : argument is not a function
    2: In formals(fun) : argument is not a function
    > Corr_matrix <- cor(mydata)
    > imputed_data <- apply(numeric_data, 2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x))
    Error in apply(numeric_data, 2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),  : 
    object 'numeric_data' not found
    > numeric_data <- mydata[, sapply(mydata, is.numeric)]
    > imputed_data <- apply(numeric_data, 2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x))
    > corr_matrix <- cor(imputed_data)
    > qgraph(corr_matrix, layout = "spring", labels = colnames(imputed_data))
    > **my_model <- estimateNetwork(corr_matrix, reg = "mgl", standardize = TRUE)
    Error in do.call(.input$estimator, c(list(data), .input$arguments)) : 
   'what' must be a function or character string
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In formals(fun) : argument is not a function
    2: In formals(fun) : argument is not a function
    > **
```

I reloaded mgm and associated packages. I restarted R and checked my previous code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you program your code in an R script rather than in the console. You now show for example also lines of code that result in an error followed by different lines of code to resolve that error, which makes reading your code very hard. Here, please note that `mgm` is a function from the *mgm* package and `estimateNetwork` is a function from the *bootnet* package that functions as a wrapper on `mgm` if you use `default = "mgm"`. This is explained in the help file `?estimateNetwork`. Also note that the input to `estimateNetwork` should be raw data and not a correlation matrix.